# If $|a-1|<\epsilon$ and $|a-2|<\epsilon$ prove that $\epsilon>1/2$

Tags: inequality

> If $|a-1|<\epsilon$ and $|a-2|<\epsilon$ prove that $\epsilon>1/2$

I know that $\epsilon -2 \le \epsilon-1 \le a$ and $a \le \epsilon+1 \le \epsilon+2$ but can I use it somehow? How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$|a-1|<\epsilon \iff -\epsilon<a-1<\epsilon\iff 1-\epsilon<a<1+\epsilon$$
$$|a-2|<\epsilon \iff -\epsilon<a-2<\epsilon\iff 2-\epsilon<a<2+\epsilon$$

therefore

$$2-\epsilon<1+\epsilon \implies 2\epsilon>1 \implies \epsilon >\frac12$$

Answer (score 2):

$1-\epsilon <a<1+\epsilon$, and (!)

$2-\epsilon <a <2+\epsilon.$

Hence

$2-\epsilon <1+ \epsilon$ (why?), or

$1/2 < \epsilon.$

What happens if $\epsilon < 1/2$ ? 
(Draw it on number line).

Answer (score 1):

If $\varepsilon\leqslant\frac12$, then$$\lvert a-1\rvert<\varepsilon\implies a<1+\varepsilon\leqslant\frac32\text{ and }\lvert a-2\rvert<\varepsilon\implies a>2-\varepsilon\geqslant\frac32.$$

Answer (score 1):

The assumption tells you that 
$$
2\epsilon>|a-1|+|a-2|
$$
which is equivalent to 
$$
\epsilon>\frac{1}{2}(|a-1|+|a-2|).
$$
Now it suffices to show that
$$
|a-1|+|a-2|\geq 1.
$$
which follows by triangle inequality or simply noticing that

- if $a<1$, then $|a-1|+|a-2|=(1-a)+(2-a)=3-a>3-1=2>1$;
- if $1\leq a\leq 2$, then $|a-1|+|a-2|=1$;
- if $a>2$, then $|a-1|+|a-2|=2a-3>2\times 2-3=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$|a-1|+|a-2|=|a-1|+|2-a|\geq \left|(a-1)+(2-a)\right|...$$